# Python code for navigating through existing url

Tags: python

I am searching for python code to navigate through url and download the resultant file i.e. The site has multiple selections to make before i get the file to be downloaded, I want all those choosing process to be done inside a code and download the resultant file

Comment: Could you try rewriting the question to be a bit clearer? You should also add the python-2.x or python-3.x tag if it is important which language version it works with, because not all the modules people might suggest you to use will work on both.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely use [Python Mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/), which implements commands like "click link" or "fill form".